# IE11 - form.$submitted being set wronly on Angular button-component click

Tags: angularjs, forms, angularjs-directive

[This plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/P18vuUrTCCnH9ZmenWF5)

I have Angular directive `bl-button` that wraps 'button' element and I am passing over `my-type` to set button's `type` attribute and `my-click` function to run something.

My problem is that, only in IE11, parent form's $submitted flag is being set even when I am passing "button" via `my-type`..?

```
  <bl-button my-click="myJob(myform)" my-type="button">Save2</bl-button>
```

In Chrome or FF, as expected, $submitted is being set only when I am saying `my-type="submit"`.

I may be missing something here.

**Edit**: below is my directive:

```
.directive('blButton', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      myClick: '&', // myClick() returns promise
      myType: '@' // by default 'button'
    },
    template: '<button type="{{myType1}}" ng-click="click()" ng-transclude></button>',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

      scope.myType1 = scope.myType || 'button';

      scope.click = function () {
        scope.myClick()
          .then(function(data) {
            console.log('resolved:', data);
          }, function(data) {
            console.log('rejected:', data);
          });
      };
    }
  };

});
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code as a [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third party site.

Comment: @Mike, edited to show directive code, if you are interested, you can also fork my plunker and suggest a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're falling into [this bug in AngularJS](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14117). The workaround, from that bug:

> Workaround: Using `ng-attr-type="{{someInterpolatedThing}}"` fixes it.

Note that this is also listed in Angular's [Internet Explorer Compatibility page](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie).

Comment: This solved my problem on IE11 with Angular1.4.2. Those links were also helpful. Thanks a lot.